# 2021 fryer test 4C

Tags: combinatorics, contest-math

[image]

[image]

**Answer: (2^36) * 13**. which is around 8.933 * 10^11

**My Solution:**
[image]

I found out that the amount of SF paths from A to B *and* C where you can't go through B to reach C and vice versa is 2^N where N is the number of squares. So in this case, it's 2^2 = 4. so there are 4 SF paths from A to B *and* C.
[image]
**please ignore the '2t' above the diagram**

The number of SF paths in the middle 4 squares where you can't cross C to reach D and vice versa:

A to C: 6 paths

A to D: 7 paths

B to C: 6 paths

B to D: 7 paths

The number of SF paths from S to A *or* B is (2^18) / 2 = 2^17. Number of SF paths from C *or* D to F is (2^18) / 2 = 2^17.

Amount of paths from S to F with every possible start and end point for the middle 4 squares:

A and C: (2^17) * 6 * (2^17) = (2^34) * 6

A and D: (2^17) * 7 * (2^17) = (2^34) * 7

B and C: (2^17) * 6 * (2^17) = (2^34) * 6

B and D: (2^17) * 7 * (2^17) = (2^34) * 7

total number of paths: (2^34) * 6 * 2 + (2^34) * 7 * 2 = around 4.667 * 10^11

I do not know why my answer isn't correct, please tell me where I went wrong.

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  In order for MathJax commands to be effective, they must be enclosed in`$` signs.  For example, `$x^2$` shows up as $x^2$.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct that the number of paths from $S$ to $A$ not using line $AB$ is $2^{17}$ and that the number of paths from $S$ to $B$ not using line $AB$ is also $2^{17}$. You are also correct that the number of paths from $A$ or $B$ to $C$ or $D$ not using $CD$ (but possibly using $AB$) is $26$.

The problem is in your asymmetric treatment of the middle four squares. Since you have allowed $AB$ to be used but not $CD$, you can't use $2^{17}$ for the count for getting from $C$ to $F$ and for getting from $D$ to $F$. In fact, you have to use $2^{18}$ for both of these counts. The reason is that you are free either to use or not use each of the last $18$ vertical segments. The vertical segment $CD$ is the $19^\text{th}$ vertical segment from the end: whether you use it or not is uniquely determined by the choices made for the last $18$ vertical segments and by whether you ended up at $C$ or $D$ at the end of your treatment of the middle four squares.

I think a symmetric treatment of $AB$ and $CD$ would simplify things. If, in your treatment of the middle four squares you didn't allow $AB$ (or $CD$) to be used, there would only be $13$ paths from $A$ or $B$ to $C$ or $D$, rather than $26$. There would then be $2^{18}$ ways of choosing whether to use each of the first $18$ vertical segments (just as for the last $18$) and whether $AB$ gets used is uniquely determined, just as argued above for $CD$.

Answer (score 0):

The number of SF paths from $S$ to $A$ or $B$ is not $2^{18}/2$ but $2^{18}$: for each of the leftmost $18$ squares exactly one of the top and bottom edges may be used (otherwise the path cannot reach $F$), and the choice of top or bottom edge determines whether there is a vertical edge or not for the left edges of those $18$ squares (not including the $AB$ edge). By symmetry a similar situation applies for the number of SF paths from $C$ or $D$ to $F$.

Then you have shown that the number of paths from $A$ or $B$ to $C$ or $D$ not using the $AB$ or $CD$ edges is $13$. Whether the $AB$ or $CD$ edges are used is completely determined by where the paths in each part ($S-AB,AB-CD,CD-F$) end, so the answer is $13\cdot2^{36}$.

Comment: How come you don't divide by 2? We can use the first diagram I made by realizing that the total amount of SF paths from A to B and C is 2^N which is 2^2 = 4. so to find the total paths to only one point, I would divide the total paths by 2 since I want to find the total paths for half the amount of points.

Comment: @Suren Why would you want to divide by $2$? There is no reason to do so.

Comment: I wanted to divide by 2 so I can find the total paths from S to A, to C or D, to F. then add it to the total paths from S to B to C or D to F. But I do not know why that gives a different and wrong answer

Comment: @Suren It should be all correct now.